# primefaces: autoComplete dropdown from left, need the opposite

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I have autocomplete with drop down, it is from left to right, I need it from right 
this is the code:

```
<f:facet name="input">
     <p:autoComplete dropdown="true" value="#{buffer.rpValue}" style="width:100%; padding:0px;"
                completeMethod="#{buffer.completeBufferOption}"
                queryDelay="50" immediate="true" />
</f:facet>
```

picture:
http://postimg.org/image/mfchcha3x/

Comment: Are you experiencing this in multiple browsers?

Comment: @kolossus no, I need it to work in chrome

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to fit the widths correctly 
specially the input width of the autoComplete